# How to use pre-trained SVM Model in R?

Tags: r

I have created a text classification SVM Model in R using RTextTools package with train dataset.

```
SVM<-train_model(train_container,"SVM")
```

Saved the above in the local using `saveRDS(SVM,file="SVM.rds")` function.
After some time in future I want to use this pre-trained model to predict the classification of new data generated(newdata is same as train data), instead training the model again and running test data on it.

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 0):

using load function

```
load(file = "SVM.rds")
```

it will seen as SVM in data enviroment